# How to save a file in such a way that only my app can open that file?

Tags: android, kotlin, encryption, storage

I am working in a project in which I have to save files like html or epub. I don't want users to copy it from their storage and run it with a different app. So  I want to save it in such a way that It can only be readable with my app. Or any other way through which I can prevent the users from opening it(both rooted &non rooted devices)

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no such a thing as completely secure way to do it, Android does provide APIs https://source.android.com/devices/drm but please consider, big companies like Spotify invest heavily in creating their own DRM system for a reason.

Comment: Store in getFilesDir().

Comment: You can try scope storage https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#other-apps-data

Comment: Its worth mentioning that you cannot prevent root from being able to read the contents of the data, regardless of where it is stored. Further, root will still be able to see the data if its encrypted with keys that exist on the device (e.g. KeyStore). And even if you do encrypt the data with keys that don't exist on the device (e.g. the data is encrypted when it is downloaded), root is able to dump a process's memory, so when you do decrypt it, root will read it then. If you're worried about root, its already game over.